# Using libcurl in c++, writing into file

Tags: php, c++, curl, libcurl

I just started using curl. So far I have managed to get my program to get a response and save it into a file/string. I am currently using it to get a response from APIs and process them. I'd be using it as a market interpretation to test various trading systems. For that purpose I plan to save the responses into tempfile, process that file and save a-ready-to-use data into another one. However, no matter string or file, my output is the one-line type.

I was wondering if there is a way to make curl directly write in a file, so its 'sorted' in lines. I mean if there is a response like:

> ```
> 4stMay2017 - Gold - open price: 1150, close price:1200 
> 3stMay2017 - Gold - open price: 1060, close price:1170 
> 2stMay2017 - Gold - open price: 1100, close price:1050 
> 1stMay2017 - Gold - open price: 1000, close price:1100
> ```

That's the way I'd like my file to look like, so I can easily sort the new data (because the market is dynamic, and the requests I'd make would be like every minute or so), and not everything is on one line. That way I have to write a write separate algorithm that will slow me down.

What my code looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
size_t size = 0;

size_t write_to_string(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, void *stream) {
    ((string*)stream)->append((char*)ptr, 0, size*count);
    return size*count;
}
int main() {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl){
        string out = string("someURL");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, out.c_str());
        string response;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_to_string);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So why not to write to file from write_to_string CB instead of appending to string? On linux you can pass filedescriptor instead of function pointer - on windows it will not work

Comment: Because it still appears unorganized. If it will stay like this, it will be easier to  process as a string.

Comment: Is should appear in the order it was sent. If you want it to be sorted list - change your code that sends the response to generate sorted list.

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer, I will research it, and implement it.